# Centered text in itext Pdf table cell

Tags: java, itext, cell

I need to center the  text inside a Pdf table cell. Unfortunately all the text is appearing at the Bottom of the cell. Here is my sample code:

```
String line = br.readLine();
Font f2 = new Font(Font.NORMAL, 12, Font.BOLD);
f2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(line, f2);
p1.setAlignment(Element.TABLE);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setBorderWidthBottom(1f);
cell.setUseBorderPadding(true);
cell.setPadding(0);
cell.setBorderColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
cell.addElement(p1);
table.addCell(cell);
output.add(table);
```

I need the text inside the cell centered vertically inside the cell. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several errors in the snippet you shared. I've adapted the code and posted an example here <s>http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/CenteredTextInCell</s> (dead link, now https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/sandbox/tables/CenteredTextInCell.java)

**Reduced overview of changes:**

The way you define a font is wrong, or you're using a version of iText that is really, really old.

The following line doesn't really make sense:

```
p1.setAlignment(Element.TABLE);
```

There is no such value in iText (there used to be one, but it has been removed a really long time ago) and evenso it doesn't make sense to use a value reserved to define an object type as to define an alignment.

If you don't want a border:

```
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

It doesn't make sense to define border widths, padding or colors:

```
cell.setBorderWidthBottom(1f);
cell.setUseBorderPadding(true);
cell.setBorderColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
```

The line you need to define vertical alignment is:

```
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Comment: @lucifer Did you try? Why ask a question you can easily answer yourself by trying? Thos question dates from 2013. It's an iText 5 question. I've moved on to iText 7 and I haven't been working on Android for about 5 years.

Comment: well, I asked because, this is not working with my code, in Android

Comment: Then you should have posted the code you tried, the result, and what is wrong with the result. You should also have mentioned which version of iText you are using. A Yes/No question isn't something you'd post on Stack Overflow; saying "it doesn't work" without any further explanation is usually not appreciated. This being said: no one will further answer your comment since it's lost in a post dating from 5 years ago.

Comment: Thank you for reply, this code doesnt work for me, but from another of your answer code, worked very well. I dont remember link of it at present, but whenever I searched my query, everytime I found post with your answer, only.

Comment: also, this link can helpful for you: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-cells

Comment: https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/sandbox/tables/CenteredTextInCell.java
Code is not working.

Answer (score 5):

```
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```